# Can multiple threads modify a dictionary?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-3.0

In C#, can multiple threads read and write to a Dictionary provided each thread only accesses one element in the dictionary and never accesses another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a Dictionary is not Thread-safe.

With the exception of modifying the contents of a reference type (object) that is stored as the Value in a dictionary.

In .NET 4 we will have `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 3):

No, they can't. A [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is not thread safe:

> A Dictionary(TKey, TValue) can support
>   multiple readers concurrently, as long
>   as the collection is not modified.
>   Even so, enumerating through a
>   collection is intrinsically not a
>   thread-safe procedure. In the rare
>   case where an enumeration contends
>   with write accesses, the collection
>   must be locked during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection
>   to be accessed by multiple threads for
>   reading and writing, you must
>   implement your own synchronization.

Comment: Yes, in C# 4.0 there's the `ConcurrentDictionary` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(VS.100).aspx) and in C# 3 you will have to implement a synchronization mechanism (`lock`, `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, ...)